# Logging sequence in $.each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery script that looks through a list of divs, and then it's children, and prints out:

1. The item's title
2. The item's description

An issue I'm noticing is that even though the two `console.log()`s are *next to each other* in the inner `$.each()`, I'd expect to see:

> Title 1 Description 1 Title 2 Description 2 Title 3 Description 3...etc

**Instead** what I'm seeing is:

> Title 1 Title 2 Title 3...etc 
>   Description 1 Description 2 Description 3...etc

---

*Updated* the inner `.find()`s:
**The script:**

```
$('.ghx-backlog').each(function(){
    $($(this).find('div[class*=has-issues]')).each(function(index){
        console.log($(this).find('.ghx-key > a').text()); //The Title
        console.log($(this).find('.ghx-summary > span').text()); //The Description
    });
});
```

**The Markup:**

```
<div id="ghx-backlog" class="ghx-backlog" data-rendered="123456789">
    <div class="ghx-issues js-issue-list ghx-has-issues">
        <div class="js-issue js-sortable js-parent-drag ghx-issue-compact ghx-type-6" data-issue-id="1233456" data-issue-key="Title 1">
            <div class="ghx-issue-content">
                <div class="ghx-row">
                    <div class="ghx-key">
                        <a href="/browse/Title 1" title="Title 1" class="js-key-link">XXXXXX-##</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ghx-summary" title="Description 1">
                        <span class="ghx-inner">Description 1</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ghx-row">
                    <div class="ghx-key">
                        <a href="/browse/Title 2" title="Title 2" class="js-key-link">XXXXXX-##</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ghx-summary" title="Description 2">
                        <span class="ghx-inner">Description 2</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show us HTML code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem:** is with this selector `$(this).find('div[class*=has-issues]')` .You have multiple `title` and multiple `Description` with in it. But next you are just doing `$(this).find('.ghx-key > a').text()` which will select all the `a` tags and gets its text, Similar issue for `Description`

**Solution:** Loop the element `.ghx-row` which is within the `div[class*=has-issues]`.

Replace your `$(this).find('div[class*=has-issues]')` with `$(this).find('div[class*=has-issues] .ghx-row')`

Working snippet below. Also I have refactored your code to have `string` in selectors rather than `Jquery Object`.

```js
$('.ghx-backlog').each(function(){
    $(this).find('div[class*=has-issues] .ghx-row').each(function(index){
        console.log($(this).find('.ghx-key > a').text()); //The Title
        console.log($(this).find('.ghx-summary > span').text()); //The Description
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ghx-backlog" class="ghx-backlog" data-rendered="123456789">
  <div class="ghx-issues js-issue-list ghx-has-issues">
    <div class="js-issue js-sortable js-parent-drag ghx-issue-compact ghx-type-6" data-issue-id="1233456" data-issue-key="Title 1">
      <div class="ghx-issue-content">
        <div class="ghx-row">
          <div class="ghx-key">
            <a href="/browse/Title 1" title="Title 1" class="js-key-link">XXX(1)XXX-##</a>
          </div>
          <div class="ghx-summary" title="Description 1">
            <span class="ghx-inner">Description 1</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ghx-row">
          <div class="ghx-key">
            <a href="/browse/Title 2" title="Title 1" class="js-key-link">XXX(2)XXX-##</a>
          </div>
          <div class="ghx-summary" title="Description 2">
            <span class="ghx-inner">Description 2</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```